# Possible reason for diverting domestic flight to a distant country

Tags: airline-operations, commercial-operations, lufthansa

I have just spotted [something weird](https://www.flightradar24.com/DLH7TV/93ecc48) (at least to me) on Flightradar24. A Lufthansa domestic flight from Munich to Frankfurt flying toward... Warsaw in Poland:

[image]

My first, and quite obvious conclusion was a Flightradar24 error, as it happens from time to time. But then, I have opened [flight LH121 recent details](https://www.flightradar24.com/flight/lh121) and to my extreme surprise it turned out, that the very same flight was diverted to Warsaw yesterday as well:

[image]

Is there any logical, business or technical explanation for this? Is there any logic at all in diverting local, domestic flight to a distant airport in not so close country? Because from mine -- real layman to airline operational rules -- this seems very, very wrong.

I mean, they have like about ten other airports in Germany, about six more in Czech Republic, not mentioning next six or seven in Poland itself, that this plane could land on, before reaching Warsaw.

Not mentioning for the fact, that looking at Flightradar24 track it seems like this plane would pointing Warsaw from the very beginning of takeoff. I mean -- Frankfurt is exactly opposite the way.

What am I missing?

Comment: So Flightradar24 had the same bug today as it had yesterday?  [According to Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=lh121), it didn't divert at all.  [According to Lufthansa](http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/uk/informationservice/flightinfo/flightstatus/application/), it arrived as scheduled also.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be asking about a software bug in a 3rd party service.

Comment: @Simon Taking the fact, that Google takes its data from _just_ the operational sources, while Flightradar24 uses actual ADS-B broadcast, intercepted and pushed in by many separate receivers, I'd more like into believing, that FR24, not Google, is correct and that this particular plane has actually flown over my house. I've heard (and spotted myself) many strange errors in FR24, but never heard about bug causing to show a plane, that is flying for 2+ hours, while it actually flown for less then hour in a bit different part of world. But.. I'm a laymen to this, so I may be very wrong.

Comment: Nope.  Google takes flight status from the airline databases.   For the absolute authority, check the Lufthansa arrivals.  According to the airline, it's aircraft landed in FRA, as scheduled.  I doubt that they are lying.

Comment: Frankfurt airport says that it is landed on schedule. I trust more the airport than a third party. http://i.imgur.com/UdqlomB.png

Comment: Also according to Lufthansa the flight was not diverted. You can go to [this site](http://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/Arrival-and-Departure-Result) and type in the flight number to get details.

Comment: OK, so it seems like a bug in FR24. Then it is really OT. Sorry. Though you should admit, that this one is really weird one. BTW, @Federico Wouldn't be easier to post a link instead of making a screenshot, cropping it and posting to imgur? :>

Comment: No problem.  The probable explanation (myth plausible) is that Flightradar24 has got the wrong call sign associated with the airframe number and that track is for a different flight altogether.

Comment: @Simon That was my first thought (expressed in question itself). However, finding out two exactly the same errors on exactly the same flight on two continuing days has just made my quite not so sure.

Comment: @trejder, since FR24 uses ADS-B, it is unlikely that it would be showing a flight track where there was no aircraft. But it might have easily assigned wrong flight plan to the aircraft. The ADS-B only broadcasts the aircraft unique identifier and the flight plan has to be taken from some other source and matched. And the matching could have gone wrong because of bug, error in data entry to that system or because the airline switched equipment and the update didn't propagate or didn't propagate yet.

Comment: The difference in equipment for the two days showing a "diversion" is also a good indicator that this was actually a different flight. [FlightAware shows](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/DLH121/history/20160328/1800Z/EDDM/EDDF) that the actual DLH121 still used A320-family aircraft on these days, as per the usual (and that it didn't divert.)